# Follow on 301 redirect using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Wondered if someone can help me. I'm trying to remove a 302 redirect from one of my sites but I can't get the code correct. It works for the first http -> https but the redirect to /tt-rss/ is still being done using 302

This is what I'm using......can anyone help?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

```
>>> http://rss.oliroe.com
> --------------------------------------------
> 301 Moved Permanently
> --------------------------------------------
Status: 301 Moved Permanently
Code:   301
Server: nginx
Date:   Wed, 05 Oct 2022 12:14:02 GMT
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 231
Connection: close
Location:   https://rss.oliroe.com/

>>> https://rss.oliroe.com/
> --------------------------------------------
> 302 Found
> --------------------------------------------
Status: 302 Found
Code:   302
Server: nginx
Date:   Wed, 05 Oct 2022 12:14:03 GMT
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
X-Powered-By:   PHP/8.1.11
Location:   /tt-rss/
Strict-Transport-Security:  max-age=15768000; includeSubdomains; preload

>>> /tt-rss/
> --------------------------------------------
> 200 OK
> --------------------------------------------
Status: 200 OK
Code:   200
Server: nginx
Date:   Wed, 05 Oct 2022 12:14:03 GMT
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
X-Powered-By:   PHP/8.1.11
Cache-Control:  public
Strict-Transport-Security:  max-age=15768000; includeSubdomains; preload
```

Comment: Could it be that you are using at a client side cached response from earlier attempts?

Comment: Who or what is redirecting to `/tt-rss/` in the first place? If the code you have shown above is _all_ you have in your .htaccess - then it can't come from there. I am seeing a login mask under that URL - so I guess it is probably a redirect caused by script code ...?

Comment: How are you testing this? All those responses appear to be coming from `Server: nginx` - how does this relate to your Apache `.htaccess` file? Your 2nd 302 redirect is triggered by `X-Powered-By:   PHP/8.1.11`. You've also implemented HSTS+preload, so you should not be seeing the HTTP-HTTPS 301 after the initial redirect.

Comment: I'm following this https://www.synoforum.com/resources/http-to-https-redirect.86/ which I guess Apache is handling the http -> https redirection but thereafter the built in nginx is taking over. I guess that could explain why the initial redirection is following the .htaccess file but thereafter it's being ignore

Comment: If I use ```RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]```  with http://rss.oliroe.com then I see a 302 to https:\\rss.oliroe.com and then a 302 to /tt-rss/ so I definitely know it's picking up the file

Comment: I've solved this, the website had this code in the index.php header("Location: /tt-rss/");, I didn't realise redirects in php defaulted to 302. Changing the line to header("Location: /tt-rss/", true, 301); solved my issues. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this, the website had this code in the index.php header("Location: /tt-rss/");, I didn't realise redirects in php defaulted to 302. Changing the line to header("Location: /tt-rss/", true, 301); solved my issues. Many thanks